# how can i embed java db in a distribution so it runs on another machine?

Tags: java, jdbc, javadb

I am designing a program that will use a large amount of database storage for information and even though it works fine while using Net beans because i start the server, what i need is to make a distribution that will run the java db on another machine by just running the program normally without a separate install and start up of other services because as it stands i have a login in dialog that wont start the rest of the program until that password is correct and this is then fed through for the database password and connection but when i run it on another machine it doesn't run because the database service doesn't start.  So i was wondering if anyone knew how to get this working?

the way which the program is setup so far:

GUI class which runs and manages just the GUI side

a coordinating class which links a bunch of other classes for the main bulk of the process etc and receives most of its info from the GUI class and returns only what is needed.

the coordinating class also runs the database connection, record and retrieve methods

so i am hoping that its just another method i can add to one of these to start the java db then run the connection.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you want exactly? To start a local server? To host your database on a remote server? Or to have an embedded database?

Comment: The database will be on a stand alone PC with no internet access so the database must be embedded within the program and the program will have to start the db side and then construct the db and tables if they dont exist.

Comment: You've tagged this question with [tag:javadb]. That's essentially Apache Derby which can be embedded. Simply use the correct JDBC URL when opening the connection—see [Syntax of database connection URLs for applications with embedded databases](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefjdbc37352.html) (from [this reference](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/index.html)). If you're using a different database (e.g. H2, SQLite, etc.) check their documentation. Not all databases can be embedded.

Comment: You may need to specify an attribute in the URL to create the database. For instance, [Derby appears to use `create=true`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefattrib26867.html) (also see http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefjdbc10889.html#rrefjdbc10889).